# What is "ALL_ALL" locale?

Tags: locale

Was unable to find any information about this, however google is using it in their source code: `view-source:https://workspace.google.com/products/gmail/`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/i18n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local names have no predefined meaning. In fact Windows uses different convention then Unix (and so Linux and macos, and that two changed name convention on how to define UTF-8 charsets).

Google is using ALL as catch all string. So ALL_ALL means all languages in all countries. Note: this convention is mostly used on "server side", so when matching client locales (which should not have ALL), and no match is found.

See e.g. https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/i18n:

> Where there is no language- or country-specific value, the convention is to use “ALL.” For example, the file de_ALL.xml applies to all German speakers, regardless of their country. The message bundle ALL_ALL.xml is the file that is used by default.